# Embed a Google Maps API Javascript in Flex

Tags: html, actionscript-3, apache-flex, google-maps-api-3, dhtml

How could I embed a Google Maps API Javascrip on my Flex Application?
I found some examples, but none of them worked for me.

http://javey.net/bike/map/player5/map.html?gpx=http://javey.net/bike/gpx/24-nov-2007.gpx&title=Sheldon.Road.Trail

Can anyone help me with that question? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I use the flex-iframe and it solves all my problems. 
If someone is having the same issue: http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Do you have any code to show us?

Your second link explains using an HTML wrapper in Flex, which seems like a straightforward solution to me. You can make sure the HTML portion is working by opening it in a browser to make sure it shows up and displays properly (often this is the real problem).

The poster of the links you gave also linked to the source code in the comments: [Flex + Google Maps](http://note19.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/flex-map/). Try modifying a copy of their code to do what you want it to. Or cut out as much of their code as you can while preserving the functionality you want to see how they do it, and go from there.

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: It's directing Luciana to take a closer look, since I think s/he already has the answer handy and doesn't know it yet.

Comment: I appreciate the motivation you gave me, mouseas. I surely make the Google Maps working. But it seems like the Flesh Builder just show the HTML. If I wanted to put this HTML inside some Flex Component for example, how should I do this? Do you know the answer? (:

Comment: I use FlashDevelop and work from the code side, so I'm not familiar with how it works in, say, Adobe CS5. But my guess is that when you're putting it together you'll see the code, but when you run it or create a finished/compiled swf, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if StageWebView is what you're after?

http://blogs.adobe.com/ria/2011/01/10/accessing-the-stagewebview-object/

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for but thank you, much appreciated *o*