# Flex 4.0 Maps Integration

Tags: google-maps, apache-flex, flex4.5

I just started working with flex 4.5 and being a new in Flex I realised that Google Maps are no longer available in Flex. I searched internet but find no solution. In fact Google site is saying that it is deprecated and we no longer give keys for it. My concern is that so there is no way to integrate it or is there any trick or so, to integrate Google Maps with Flex 4.5. Or may be I missed some point of integration.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google Maps for Flash/Flex seem to be abandoned, but you can use [MapQuest maps](http://devgirl.org/2011/12/06/flex-mobile-development-adding-maps-with-mapquest-flash-api-w-sample-app/), even in a Flex Mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Maps API for Flash](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/) has been officially deprecated as of September 2, 2011. There are workarounds and alternative map services mentioned here:

- [Embed a Google Maps API Javascript in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108677/embed-a-google-maps-api-javascript-in-flex)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713760/which-maps-api-for-flex